# Using ODBC Connection to Access Firebird Database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, linked-server, odbc, firebird

I have an ODBC connection to a Firebird database that tests successfully.  Is there a way to use this ODBC connection within SQL  Server 2008 R2 to access the tables?  I haven't used Linked Servers before and wasn't sure if that was an option...and if so, what would be the provider needed/desired?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to create a Linked Server to almost any ODBC data source.

I would suggest trying the `Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers`.

While you need to enter something in the `Product Name` field, I believe you can enter anything, such as "Firebird".

For `Data Source`, enter the name of the ODBC System DSN you've previously created.

You'll need to confirm the other options for "Security" and "Server Options", and test to see if it works.